# DCPromo Before or After?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, windows, active-directory

I have an older Windows 2003 Server that is doing moderate duty right now -- small SQL database and an LOB application.

I plan to:

1. Make it a DC.
2. Install DHCP/DNS/WINS as backup for the FSMO role-holder, a 2008 server that's already a DC.

Here's the basic question: **Would you DCPROMO the 2003 server before or after you install and configure those roles? Is there any difference?**

A little more background: I'm doing this because of a different server which is beginning to get a bit creaky. We want to gracefully retire it, move primary FSMO roles to the 2008 server and take the moderate-activity 2003 server and expand its duties. We also would like to reduce power consumption in the server closet and increase runtime for our new UPS.

Comment: Make sure your domain functional level is still 2003. If it's higher then you can't add a 2003 DC.

Comment: The functional level is 2003. I imagine that's because of the current 2003-era DC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ideal world, I would not use a Domain Controller for anything other than AD DS.  But if you're gonna do it anyway, then DCPROMO it first.  DCPROMO installs DNS at the same time as Directory Services.  Go from there.

Comment: I agree with you. We have a pretty good situation here. While Old DC is Old, there's no urgent reason to retire it. Maybe what I can do instead would be to transfer FSMO role-holding to the 2008 server that's already a DC. I can expand 2008 server's role a bit and put a dumb UPS on the old DC. So, were it to die we'd be in pretty good shape. That way, I can leave LOB server alone. Hmmmm...

Comment: Out voted. Booooooooooooooooooooooo...